# Using Snowflake as Type inside Mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

**Background**: Discord.js identifies many items using Snowflakes (messages, members, guilds, etc.). In my scenario, I am using snowflakes as unique identifiers for members inside the guild and as the primary key inside my MongoDB database.

**Problem**: I am wanting to use Discord's Snowflake as a type inside my Mongoose schema:

```js
import { Snowflake } from 'discord.js';
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const MembershipSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    discordID: { type: Snowflake, required: true, unique: true },
});
```

However, I get an error from VSCode's Intellisense telling me that `'Snowflake' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` I am confused because my interpretation from the Discord.js documentation was that `Snowflake` was a type (essentially just a `string`).

I can definitely simply use `string` instead but I am wondering if there is any way to make it work similar to how I have shown above. I want it to be really explicit that the value going inside the `discordID` field must be a `Snowflake`, not any old string.

Comment: Snowflake is just a string, you can say String can’t you?

Comment: @MrMythical Yep, you can simply use a string for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the most appropriate method for enforcing the types partially includes the answers provided by @MrMythical and @Toasty. However, their answers are incomplete and should not be followed completely to achieve my goal here.

Essentially, the solution I found after some more hours of research was to simply add a typing interface to the model when it is created. At least in VSCode, Intellisense will recognize this and will enforce the types on the defined schema parameters based on what was in the interface.

An example is shown below:

**MembershipModel.ts**

```js
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
import Membership from '../interfaces/MembershipStorage';

const MembershipSchema: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        discordID: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        ieeeID: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    },
    {
        collection: 'members',
        minimize: false,
        strictQuery: true,
    }
);

export default model<Membership>('Member', MembershipSchema);
```

**MembershipStorage.ts**

```js
import { Snowflake } from 'discord.js';

export default interface Membership {
    discordID: Snowflake;
    ieeeID: string;
}
```